# It is possible to create a custom marker view in Katalon studio?

Tags: katalon-studio, katalon

I’m currently working on a katalon Studio plugin that receives a list of items (after processing) that I want to display on a “custom marker view” (similar to the problems view) it is that possible in Katalon studio 8.1.0??

[Problems marker view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRWur.png)

If the answer is yes, can you share with me any kind of documentation or knowledge that I can use to accomplish that?

Thank you!!

Comment: You can print it in the console. What is wrong with that?

Comment: @MateMrše, there is nothing wrong with that, I just wanted to do something more user-friendly, but I guess that the console is my only option.